# Phone gap Error! Unable to open asset URL file

Tags: android, cordova

When running android app it showing error:

```
file:///android_asset/www/images/ajax-loader.gif Unable to open asset URL:file:///android_asset/www/images/go.jpg
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: do you have the `go.jpg` located in your `www/images` folder?

Comment: go.jpg located in my asset/www/img/folder

Comment: But there is no folder images!

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings:

1. Make sure you have the file in the directory
2. Specify permission for read/write to the file
3. android file name are case-sensitive.

Why the gif and jpg both comes in one error...check it.

Comment: Does android support jpg images.if not how can i change image extension to support android ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html 
try to use as described there(i preferred png)